# I am unable to print the text using java.io.printstream

Tags: java

I am trying to print an epl label using `java.io.printstream` but when
I click on the print button nothing happens, print is not coming out.

Here is my code

```
String printerShareValue = printerTextField.getText().trim();
FileOutputStream printerStream = new FileOutputStream(printerShareValue);

PrintStream ps = new MyPrintStream(printerStream);
ps.print("\f");
ps.print(printTextArea.getText());
ps.flush();
ps.close();
```

`printerTextField` contains printer name which is going to print.

`printTextArea` is the text label we want to print.

```
 class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream { 
   public MyPrintStream(OutputStream outp) { super(outp); } 
   @Override 
   public void print(String s) { super.print(s); } 
 }


public class TestPrint extends JFrame {

private Container contentPane;
private final int VERTICAL_RIGID_AREA_HEIGHT = 30;
private final int STANDARD_LABEL_HEIGHT = 20;
private final int STANDARD_LABEL_WIDTH = 100;
private JTextField printerTextField;
private JTextArea printTextArea;

public TestPrint() {
    super();
    contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    setTitle("PrintTest");

    addRigidArea(contentPane, 0, VERTICAL_RIGID_AREA_HEIGHT);
    setupPrintPanel();
    setupPrinterTextArea();
    setupButtons();
    addRigidArea(contentPane, 0, 20);
    pack();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle gcr = gc.getBounds();
    Rectangle thisr = getBounds();
    setLocation(new Point(gcr.x + (gcr.width / 2) - (thisr.width / 2), gcr.y
            + (gcr.height / 2) - (thisr.height / 2)));
    setVisible(true);

}

private void setupPrintPanel() {
    // setup the panel
    JPanel panel = setupPanel();
    exactly(panel, 500, 40);

    addRigidArea(panel, 10, 0);
    printerTextField = new JTextField();

    // the JComboBox dropdown list element
    JLabel databaseLabel = new JLabel("Eltron Label Printer Share");
    databaseLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    exactly(databaseLabel, 150, STANDARD_LABEL_HEIGHT);
    panel.add(databaseLabel);

    addRigidArea(panel, 10, 0);
    printerTextField = new JTextField();
    exactly(printerTextField, 300, STANDARD_LABEL_HEIGHT);
    panel.add(printerTextField);

    contentPane.add(panel);

}

private void setupPrinterTextArea() {
    JPanel panel = setupPanel();

    addRigidArea(panel, 10, 0);

    printTextArea = new JTextArea();
    String s = "N\n"
            + "A50,1150,3,2,2,1,N,\"SHIP TO:\"\n"
            + "A50,950,3,3,2,1,N,\"test\"\n"
            + "B100,384,3,1,3,7,90,B,\"1046305\"\n"
            + "A90,950,3,3,2,1,N,\"tt\"\n"
            + "A130,950,3,3,2,1,N,\"tttt\"\n"
            + "A170,950,3,3,2,1,N,\"tttt\"\n"
            + "A210,950,3,3,2,1,N,\"ttt, CO  ttt  t\"\n"
            + "A270,1150,3,2,2,1,N,\"ORDER #\"\n"
            + "A270,880,3,2,2,1,N,\"PURCHASE ORDER #\"\n"
            + "A270,200,3,2,2,1,N,\"SHIP DATE\"\n"
            + "A300,1150,3,3,2,1,N,\"087462\"\n"
            + "A300,880,3,3,2,1,N,\"\"\n"
            + "A300,200,3,3,2,1,N,\"06-12-2018\"\n"
            + "A350,1150,3,2,2,1,N,\"TAG:\"\n"
            + "A350,1090,3,3,2,1,N,\"\"\n"
            + "A400,1150,3,2,2,1,N,\"ITEM #\"\n"
            + "A400,880,3,2,2,1,N,\"DESCRIPTION\"\n"
            + "A400,200,3,2,2,1,N,\"QUANTITY\"\n"
            + "A430,1150,3,3,2,1,N,\"2601400 01SI1T(H\"\n"
            + "A430,880,3,3,2,1,N,\"DOUBLE HUB MINI LARGE PLATINUM COATED \"\n"
            + "A430,200,3,3,2,1,N,\"1\"\n"
            + "A480,1150,3,3,2,1,N,\"B02MCL-PLT)[1000]\"\n"
            + "A530,1150,3,4,2,1,N,\"SAM123\"\n"
            + "A480,880,3W,3,2,1,N,\"WITH PAINTED OF HB02MCL-PLT\"\n"
            + "A530,880,3,3,2,1,N,\"FOR MONITORS BETWEEN 2-10LBS.\"\n"
            + "A580,1150,3,3,2,1,N,\"Test sales order note.\"\n"
            + "A610,1150,3,2,2,1,N,\"GROSS WEIGHT\"\n"
            + "A610,880,3,2,2,1,N,\"NET WEIGHT\"\n"
            + "A610,600,3,2,2,1,N,\"CARTON SIZE\"\n"
            + "A640,1150,3,3,2,1,N,\"2.0(Kg)\"\n"
            + "A640,880,3,3,2,1,N,\"3.0(Kg)\"\n"
            + "A640,600,3,3,2,1,N,\"4.0(mm)X0.0(mm)X0.0(mm)\"\n"
            + "P1";
    exactly(printTextArea, 500, 550);
    printTextArea.setText(s);
    panel.add(printTextArea);
    addRigidArea(panel, 10, 0);
    contentPane.add(panel);

}

private void setupButtons() {
    JPanel panel = setupPanel();
    exactly(panel, 150, 50);

    //The ok Button
    JButton okButton = new JButton("Print");
    okButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    okButton.setEnabled(true);
    okButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            printButtonAction();
        }
    });
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
    okButton.requestFocusInWindow();
    panel.add(okButton);
    addRigidArea(panel, 10, 0);
    contentPane.add(panel);
}

private void printButtonAction() {
    try {           
        if(printerTextField.getText().trim().length() == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Eltron Label Printer Share Path To Print Labels Same As In Spaceco ", "Enter Printer", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return; 
        }
        String printerShareValue = printerTextField.getText().trim();
        FileOutputStream printerStream = new FileOutputStream(printerShareValue);
        PrintStream ps = new MyPrintStream(printerStream);
        ps.print("\f");
        ps.print(printTextArea.getText());
        ps.flush();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String message = ex.getMessage() + "" + ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "No Printer", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}

/**
 * used to print the labels on the eltron label printer
 */
static class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    public MyPrintStream(OutputStream outp) {
        super(outp);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        super.print(s);
    }
}

/**
 * Adds some rigid area with given widht and height
 */
protected void addRigidArea(Container c, int width, int height) {
    c.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(width, height)));
}

/**
 * Fixes the size to a component
 */
protected void exactly(JComponent jc, int width, int height) {
    Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
    jc.setMaximumSize(d);
    jc.setMinimumSize(d);
    jc.setPreferredSize(d);
}

/**
 * Sets up a JPanel with Box Layout in X-axis
 */
protected JPanel setupPanel() {
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    return jp;
}

}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: We need to see the whole code, specially `MyPrintStream`

Comment: class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream {

        public MyPrintStream(OutputStream outp) {
            super(outp);
        }

        @Override
        public void print(String s) {
            super.print(s);
        }
    }

Comment: We need **all** the code. You mention clicking, we need your GUI code as well. Do you get any exception ?

Comment: `MyPrintStream` appears to be completely pointless. Are you aware that `PrintStream` swallows exceptions? Do you call the `check()` method?

Comment: k.no i didn't call any check() method.can you please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you click the "Print" button ?

Comment: i need to print the label  based on the text on printtexarea.I want to get the print of label from the entered printer

Comment: @REDDY define 'print'. Is it 'print in the console', 'print on a file', 'print on paper' ?

Comment: no need on console.just i need to print it one the paper.The text contains the epl commands to print the epl label

Comment: Your code will only write the content of the `printTextArea` on a file name after the content of `printerShareValue`. Sending data to a paper printer is complete different story. You can find some example online, like this one http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-print-a-text-file-with-javax.print-api.html

Comment: my doubt is  printstream.print(printTextArea.getText()) will directly print the text entered in the printTextarea am i correct or not.

Comment: because we have a method in PrintStream like print(String s) to print the string

Comment: @REDDY You need to read the JAVA IO tutorial. Do not guess method purpose from their name. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Comment: can you please correct my code where i am wrong plz.it would be hepfull for me

Comment: cam you please provide me the correct code.I have struck with this

Comment: Where you're wrong is in not calling the `check()` method. This seems rather obvious after what I said above.

Comment: can you please tell me where i want to write check() method

Answer (score 0):

Well uhm... You can't just create a new `PrintStream` and print messages to it, if you want the messages to appear in the console, you should use the `PrintStream` instance of `System.out`.